# Vue cli passing props (data) through router-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am using `Vue-cli` with vue-router installed, inside my `App.vue` I've got `<router-link  to="/about" >About</router-link>` in which it's going to display the content of about component on click. Now, I would like to pass props data to `About.vue` component from `` App.vue. Adding :myprops="myprops" inside `<router-link to="/about" :myprops="myprops">About</router-link>` didn't work that's why I add the following to `App.vue` :

```
<script>
import About from './components/About.vue';
export default {
  name: 'App',
 components:{'my-about':About}
  data(){return {...}
  },
props:{myprops:[{.....}]}
}
</script>
```

Inside `About.vue` component I did `props:['myprops']` to get the props data and by using `{{myprops}}` to display it.
Now, if inside `App.vue`, I add `<my-about :myprops="myprops"></my-about>` then the props data will be handed over to `About.vue` and will be display but the content of `About.vue` also will be display on my `App.vue` page and also, it is going to repeat itself inside `About.vue`. I don't want that. I just need to pass the `myprops` data to `About.vue` component without displaying the `About.vue` content inside `App.vue`.
And, this is my path code inside `router/index.js` for reference:
`{ path: '/about', component: About  }`

How can I be able to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Router is not meant to be used to pass data around. It's meant to map URLs to coponents. So what you can do is to pass the props in the URL, as params or query parameters. *(If hat doesn't suit your requirements, you will likely need a real state management solution like Vuex)*

A Param has to be defined in the route definition ([see here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)) and it seems you don't want that.

You can pass the info as a query parameter, the link looks like this:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/about', query: { myprop: 'someValue' }}">
  About
</router-link>
```

The resulting URL will end up looking like this:

```
/about?myprop=somevalue
```

Then, this query parameter is available as `this.$route.query.myprop` in any component. To pass it as an actual prop to the `About` component specifically, you need to [configure the router to do so](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components):

```
{
  path: '/about', 
  component: About,
  props(route) {
    return {  myprop: route.query.myprop }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. By the way, as I am a beginner in Vue and my background is PHP, do you think I should jump right into  Vuex or stick with Vue. My goal is to use wordpress as a back end and use Vue frame work as front end. Where should I be my focus (learn Vuex or stay with learning Vue) ?

Comment: @LinusBorg binding needs colon at router-link `:to`

Comment: Right, fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

*This assumes you are not a beginner at Vue.*

**1** -  Define a prop on the target component

```
export default {
    name: "MyComponent",
    props: {
        exampleProp: Object
    }
}
```

**2** - Define a route with **props: true**

```
...
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/mycomponent',
            name: 'MyComponent',
            component: MyComponent,
            props: true
        },
...
```

**3** - Use route **name** on the router-link instead of path, and pass the props as params.

```
<router-link 
    :to="{ name: 'MyComponent', 
           params: { exampleProp: examplePropValue }}">
    Link to My Component
</router-link>
```

Comment: Does this dirty the url though? ill have to try it. Thanks

Comment: The URL remains clean; only the path changes.